# Revert to previous commit but keep recent discarded commits / code for reference

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I developing an app in Android Studio for a uni assignment. Unfortunately I seem to have gone down a bit of a blind alley and need to go back a few commits. But for reporting purposes I will need to keep a reference to the code I will be discarding and refer back to it on what I was doing, the problems I ran into etc.

So before I go back, can I be sure that the previous code will still be able to be viewed / referenced, even if it is not being used. I just want to make sure before I do anything. My experience with git version control in AS so far is simply making commits and pushing to github. This will be the first time going back or branching off so to speak.

Thanks

Comment: `can I be sure that the previous code will still be able to be viewed` it's a bit hard to answer without actually seeing what you're trying to do, at least that's my opinion, but _perhaps_ you can create a branch from where you currently are, checkout, commit and then go back to wherever you want ?

Comment: So I will be referring back to specific aspects of the discarded code in my report. I will also be including a link to the project repo on github where the assessors may also like to view the discarded code also even though it is not part of the source code of the final submission

Comment: i think the best answer anyone can give you is to learn more about git, especially considering you're unsure of what to do here. so make another project, learn some git, apply that here. you'll probably end up doing what i suggested first

Comment: create a branch call it "blind_alley" then add your files and commit them, after this they will be safe and you will have time to read some tuto about using git :)